# How to position div without space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have six divs in my html document.

My problem is that last div has some top space which needs to be removed.

This is not a duplicate question.

This has nothing to do with inline-block spacing.

Please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
  div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    position: relative;
  }
  div:first-child {
    background: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var myDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    myDivs[2].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Added fiddle.Please check that. I dont want top space to be there for my last div

Comment: Remove `inline-block` and add `float: left`. If you have whitespaces in your html `inline-block` will add some space.

Comment: float:left and vertical-align:top adding both worked.but which one should be prefered.Please explain.

Comment: Don't use `float: left` for this case. If you are using `float: left`, you need to `clear` as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: @SrikanthReddyKarnati Did it answer your question?

Comment: @gcampbell Not a valid dupe target. This is different.

Comment: @PraveenKumar "All divs should align properly without any spaces between them"?

Comment: @gcampbell True. Not a right dupe target. Let me repeat, not a right dupe target. `:)`

Comment: Use text-align or vertical-align (can't remember which off the top of my head)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with `inline-block`. Use `vertical-align: top` to fix, as the default is `baseline`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
  div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;   /* This is the fix */
  }
  div:first-child {
    background: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var myDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    myDivs[2].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a small change in your css:

```
div {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 1px solid;
display: inline-block; /* Removed this */
width: 25%;
height: 25%;
position: relative;
float:left; /* Added this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add to body `font-size: 0;` and add to your div

```
font-size: 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
```

about **[Box Sizing](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)**

**Demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
font-size: 0;
  }
  div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    position: relative;
font-size: 12px;
box-sizing: border-box;
vertical-align: top;
  }
  div:first-child {
    background: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var myDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    myDivs[2].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try absolute positioning. Add `position: absolute;` to `div:first-child`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
  div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    position: relative;
  }
  div:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var myDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    myDivs[2].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In html, spaces, tabulations and linebreak (while formatting your html document) are transcribe by a space.

So if you want no space between your div you should put comments between them :

```css
  body {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
  div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    position: relative;
  }
  div:first-child {
    background: black;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div></div><!--
  --><div></div><!--
  --><div></div><!--
  --><div></div><!--
  --><div>
  </div><!--
  --><div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var myDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    myDivs[2].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```